Publishing Service Dashboard is empty
We have Sitecore 10.3.1 installed and setup, with Sitecore Publishing Service 7.0.20 and Sitecore Publishing Service Module 10.3.0.
Publish itself works fine for all targets: items have appeared in corresponding databases. But when we navigate to the Publishing Dashboard - it is empty (no active/queued/completed jobs).
There is an error in the browser console:
ERROR [Sitecore Services]: HTTP GET
URL https://site-cm.azurewebsites.net/sitecore/api/ssc/publishing/jobs/{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}/All?recentJobRecords=8&queuedJobRecords=8&sourceDatabase=master

Exception Refit.ValidationApiException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
   at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation`1.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<<BuildCancellableTaskFuncForMethod>b__0>d.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\Refit\RequestBuilderImplementation.cs:line 258

Our environment is hosted on Azure Web Apps, with a separate web app for the publishing service.
We have tried the below:

Rebuilding the master index
Clearing the dbo.Publishing_JobQueue table in master database


Hi S. C.. is this issue resolved as we are also seeing the same issue? please let me know if you have any solution/fix for it.

Without the log details its hard to precisely identify the problem, but you can experiment with these steps to see if they offer any solutions.
Try accessing the API endpoint mentioned in the error message (/sitecore/api/ssc/publishing/jobs/{jobId}/All) directly from a browser or Postman. See if it returns the expected data or if it also produces a 400 error.
If the API URL is working fine, there might be an issue with how the Dashboard is retrieving and displaying the data.

Check the logs of the Sitecore Publishing Service to see if there are
any errors or warnings related to fetching or processing publishing
jobs.
Check if publishing server is able to call your Sitecore CM Instance. There is
no network issues
Make sure that the user accessing the Publishing Dashboard has
the necessary permissions to view publishing jobs. In some cases,
access restrictions can prevent the Dashboard from displaying data.

If it doesn't help. can you share the logs of publishing server

Azure App Service forces a redirect from HTTP requests to HTTPS. During this redirection Azure also switches http method from POST to GET. Such request can't be mapped to Publishing Service controller and returns "Bad Request" response error.
To resolve the issue please ensure that Publishing Service uses HTTPS instead.The Url is defined in the "PublishingService.UrlRoot" setting from \App_Config\Modules\PublishingService\Sitecore.Publishing.Service.config configuration file
